# Show that the set of linear hyperbolic vector fields with $\dim E^{s} = k $ is open in $ \mathcal{L} (\mathbb {R}^{d}, \mathbb {R} ^ {d }) $.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Show that for $k = 1, \ldots, d$, the set of hyperbolic linear vector fields with $\dim  E^{s} = k$ is open in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{d},\mathbb{R}^{d})$.

---

### Definition

1. $A\colon \mathbb{R}^{d} \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is linear *hyperbolic* if all its eigenvalues ​​have non-zero real part.
2. If $A\colon \mathbb{R}^{d} \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is a linear hyperbolic field, then there is a direct sum decomposition $ \mathbb{R}^{d} = E^{s} \oplus E^{u}$ satisfying:

   - the eigenvalues ​​of $A \vert E^{s}$ are the eigenvalues ​​of $A$ whose real part is negative.
   - the eigenvalues ​​of $A \vert E^{u}$ are the eigenvalues ​​of $A$ whose real part is positive.

*Attempt:* I tried to use the fact that the set of hyperbolic linear vectors is open and dense in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{d},\mathbb{R}^{d})$, but I was unsuccessful.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: All you need to show is that the eigenvalues depend continuously on the coefficients. You can find references for that fact here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556137/eigenvalues-are-continuous

Comment: why is that enough?

Comment: @KauaneAraujo Because for a hyperbolic linear map we have that $\operatorname{dim}(E^s)$ equals the number of eigenvalues with negative real part. Hence, if you want to keep the dimension fix, then you just need to ensure that number of eigenvalues with negative real part does not change. If you know continuity, then this follows immediately.

Comment: @Severin Schraven Got it. thanks!

Comment: @KauaneAraujo Great :) glad I could help.