# Is there some condition guarantees continuous hermitian matrix $H(t)$ has continuous eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have a hermitian matrix $H(t)$ continuously depend on parameter $t$, it's easy to know that the eigenvalue $\lambda_i(t)$ of it is continuous$^1$, but what about eigenvectors of it? Is there some theorem tells us that in what condition of $H(t)$, the continuous eigenvectors will be guaranteed?

This question is duplicated with [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/718751/are-the-instantaneous-eigenstates-of-a-time-dependent-hamiltonian-continuous) while I think it will be better answered here.

---

<sup>1. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556137/eigenvalues-are-continuous).</sup>

Comment: I'd like not to score from this question. XD

Comment: A sufficient for "continuity of eigenvectors", i.e. the existence of a continuous paremeterization of the eigenvectors, is that $H(t)$ has distinct eigenvalues for all $t$.

Comment: I have added another (self contained answer) to [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/718751/are-the-instantaneous-eigenstates-of-a-time-dependent-hamiltonian-continuous) Perhaps it can be helpful for solving your question.